# SQL query not executing via php, can't find the error source

Tags: php, sql

I created the ***artists*** table using the command:

```
$sql  = "CREATE TABLE artists (
            id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
            username VARCHAR(20), 
            password VARCHAR(20), 
            first_name VARCHAR(20), 
            last_name VARCHAR(50), 
            email VARCHAR(30), 
            phone VARCHAR(15), 
            genre VARCHAR(20), 
            location VARCHAR(20), 
            description VARCHAR(3000), 
            promo VARCHAR(200), 
            soundclound VARCHAR(100), 
            instruments VARCHAR(100), 
            event_type VARCHAR(100), 
            youtube VARCHAR(100), 
            experience VARCHAR(10), 
        PRIMARY KEY (id) 
    );";
$database->query($sql);
```

I would like to simply add a record of username and password to the table created above. I have a function which creates the following SQL query when I echo it:

```
INSERT INTO artists 
            (id,username,password,first_name,last_name,
            email,phone,genre,location,description,
            promo,soundcloud,instruments,event_type,youtube,
            experience) 
    VALUES ('', '12345', '12345', '', '', 
            '', '', '', '', '', 
            '', '', '', '', '', 
            '')
```

However, when I remove the `echo $sql` and call `$database->query($sql)` , it returns an error.

It works when I simply use the SQL

```
INSERT INTO artists (first_name,last_name) VALUES ('12345','12345')
```

**EDIT:**
I've edited the function that goes through every single field, and inserts and id as well:

```
 // if ($database->query($sql)) {
 // $this->id = $database->insert_id();
 // return true;} else {return false;}
 echo $sql;
```

It returns the following:

```
INSERT INTO artists (username,password,first_name,last_name,email,phone,genre,location,description,promo,soundcloud,instruments,event_type,youtube,experience) VALUES ('133', '133', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')
```

But when I try to run it, I still get an error.

I tried a simple query `INSERT INTO artists (username,password) VALUES ('123','123')` which works fine

Comment: Don't bother giving a value to the `id` because it is already auto incremented. And please include the error it returns

Answer (score 4):

the error  is the ''  (string empty )  for ID (int declared)  value  and the correct solution is baed  on

don't insert the ID (is auto_increment)

```
INSERT INTO artists (
    ,username
    ,password
    ,first_name
    ,last_name
    ,email
    ,phone
    ,genre
    ,location
    ,description
    ,promo
    ,soundcloud
    ,instruments
    ,event_type
    ,youtube
    ,experience) 
VALUES (
    '12345'
    , '12345'
    , ''
    , ''
    , ''
    , ''
    , ''
    , ''
    , ''
    , ''
    , ''
    , ''
    , ''
    , ''
    , '');
```

the error  is the ''  (string empty ) for and int  value

Comment: So that is really the problem, and here I thought it is just a small part of the error that's why I commented it haha

Comment: @CarlJan   .i have updated  the answer with the error cause

Comment: Nice. OP didn't include the error that's why I'm not sure if my comment is correct or not

Comment: Thanks, I modified the code, but still seem to be getting the error

Comment: The query seems  correct   .. then update  your question  show the exact error message ..